# Sqrt disappeared when exporting plot to PDF in version 10

Tags: export, bugs, pdf-format

**Bug introduced in 10.0.1 or 10.0.2 and fixed in 10.1.0**

---

In version 10, if we plot with `Sqrt` in y-axis, and export to PDF, the square root disappears in the PDF file.

```
p = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(y\)]\)"}]
```

[image]

```
Export["test.pdf", p];
```

[image]

This does not happen in version 9.

Comment: I can reproduce this on OS X, v 10.0.0.  Can you report this problem to support at wolfram.com?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for reproducing it. I reported a bug.

Comment: Present in 10.0.1 as well.

Comment: Still there in 10.0.2

Comment: Confirm it works in 9 but not in 10.0.2 (OS X 10.10.1). Incidentally if you want to use boxes in your labels it might be easier to do this `{DisplayForm@SqrtBox["x"], DisplayForm@SqrtBox["y"]}`. Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69242/ratio-of-variables-axeslabel-is-messed-up-when-plot-exported-to-pdf

Comment: Same behavior on 10.0.2 (Win7 64).

Comment: Did you report it?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes I did :)

Comment: Fixed in 10.1.0 but now I use [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) anyway ... motivated precisely by these types of problems.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks! It's nice to know MaTeX. I will have a try.

Comment: @Szabolcs the question you are referring to was posted months later than this question.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I chose that one as the "main" one in the cloud of duplicates for two reasons: (1) it easier to see what's going on due to the screenshot (2) we already closed [another question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75755/12) as a duplicate of that one tonight.  Actually I didn't find this thread until later.  I don't have a strong opinion on which one should be the main one, I just took the path of least resistance, to be honest ....

Comment: @Szabolcs: MaTeX is amazing... Thanks for posting the link. I can't believe I didn't know about this earlier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a bug. Stupid workaround:

```
Export["t:\\test.pdf", ImportString@ExportString[p, "EPS"]]
```

At the very least, there's a good chance that this would output reasonable vector graphics.

Or,

```
p = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, Sqrt[y]}]
```

The latter is what I usually do, anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very clever workaround :) I actually also tried the second method. However, my actual y-axis is quite complicated and I don't want Mathematica to automatically format the equation for me. So a string is preferred.

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be when the label is rotated.
Check this:

```
Export["test.pdf", 
 ListPlot[{1, 2, 3}, Joined -> False, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {Rotate["\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(x\)]\)", \[Pi]/2], 
    "\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(y\)]\)"}]]
```

however if you accept unrotated label, you can use:

```
Export["test.pdf", 
 ListPlot[{1, 2, 3}, Joined -> False, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(x\)]\)", "\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(y\)]\)"}, 
  RotateLabel -> False]]
```

[image]