# Ratio of variables AxesLabel is messed up when plot exported to pdf

Tags: plotting, pdf-format, labeling

On the vertical axis of a Plot whenever I have a ratio of variables in a string as axes label, the exporting of the plot to PDF format messes this ratio up. Minimal working example:

```
Export["test.pdf", 
 Plot[0, {x, 0, 1}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"c", "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(a\), \(b\)]\)"}
 ]
]
```

This with Mathematica 10.0.2 produces the following image:

[image: the ratio a/b is displayed problematic]

Is there any way to resolve this issue where a/b is not shown correctly within the exported PDF by Mathematica?

Comment: I get the same with 10.0.2. Also when rewriting as `DisplayForm@FractionBox["a", "b", Beveled -> False]`. Ditto with `Beveled->True`. It looks like a bug

Comment: Is there maybe another way to display fractions in a useful and neat way?

Answer (score 2):

This may be a workaround :

`Export["test.pdf", 
 Plot[0, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"c", ToString[\!\(\*FractionBox[\(a\), \(b\)]\)]}]]`

Simply wrap `ToString` around and you will get the correct output.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to fix this I found out is not using rotated labels on the y-axis using the command:

```
RotateLabel -> False
```

This does not solve the bug itself though.